# Update iScroll when data is loaded with JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, iscroll

I have a list which is generated with JSON and it works just fine. Now I want to refresh this list every 20 seconds and that is working perfectly too. But I want to be able to update my iScroll as soon as the data is generated, but as it is now, it waits the 20 seconds and then updates the scroll length. I don't know where to start and hoping for help...
Here is my script:

```
var userid=1,

dataUrl = 'http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid,
dataCallback = function (data) {
    var content = [];
    //var profile = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        content.push(val.list); // GETTING ALL THE GAMES //
        $('#userbar').html(val.profile); // FETCHING USERS DATA FOR PROFILEBAR //
    });
    $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
},
fetchData = function () {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
    if (myScroll.isReady()){
        $.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
    }
};
fetchData();
setInterval(fetchData, 20000);

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200);  }, false);
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think `#userbar` and `#games` are within `#wrapper` element. Because each time you updates these elements. I hope this helps:

```
$(function(){
myScroll = null;
dataCallback = function(data) {
    if (myScroll) { // before reuse it, completely destroy the myScroll and free some memory
        myScroll.destroy();
        myScroll = null;
    }
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
    var content = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        content.push(val.list); // GETTING ALL THE GAMES //
        $('#userbar').html(val.profile); // FETCHING USERS DATA FOR PROFILEBAR //
    });
    $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
    setTimeout(function(){
        myScroll.refresh(); // refresh to show  correct dimensions
    }, 0);
}
fetchData = function () {
    var userid = 1;
    var dataUrl = 'http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid;
    $.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
}
fetchData();
setInterval(fetchData, 20000);
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200);  }, false);
```